# Serialize class variables sequentially to byte array in C# vice versa

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

**Question**

I have a class just has numeric fields marshaled logically.

And I receive some bytes exactly match (the order of bytes are order of variables) with these class. I would like to assign these bytes to these class.

Can I code a specific Serialize method?

**To exice an example ;**

I have a sequential byteArray exactly match with Frame class, I meant this;

-01-02-03-04-05-06.... In Frame class header field's **"a"** variables value is **0x01**, **"b"** varible is **0x02** and then 4 bytes ( c is an Int32) **03-04-05-06** then it continue with val variable.

```
public class Frame
{
    public FrameHeader header;
    public FrameValue val;

}

public class FrameHeader
{
    public byte a;
    public byte b;
    public int c;
}

public class FrameValue
{
  public int x,y;
}
```

Comment: Is the format necessary? Why not just use `BinaryFormatter` (which will compactly serialize it for you)?

Comment: Yes, feel free to code it up. Did you just need a permission or there is something more to your question? (Maybe you are asking how [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) class called?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm trying to convert a `C` code to `C#` one.  There is a usage in `C`. C program deserialize this bytes `sequentially` . I just wondered if I can apply same logic here. I wonder if I obtain same thing if I use BinaryFormatter or something else.

Comment: I especially need bytes to class. So how these bytes turns to my spesific class. I mean what will happen if I use BinaryFormatter's derserialize method.Is there a usage like `binaryFormatter<MyFrameClass>(bytes)`. I wonder this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, this example of converting byte[] to int helps you?

```
byte[] bytes = { 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06 };

// If the system architecture is little-endian (that is, little end first), reverse the byte array.
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
{
    Array.Reverse(bytes);
}

int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
Console.WriteLine("int: {0}", i);
```